# How to set property of explicitly implemented interface?

Tags: c#, interface, properties, compilation, explicit

I've this code snippet:

```
public interface Imy
{
    int X { get; set; }
}

public class MyImpl : Imy
{
    private int _x;
    int Imy.X
    {
        get => _x;
        set => _x = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new MyImpl();
        o.Imy.X = 3;//error
        o.X = 3;//error
    }
}
```

I just wish to assign value to X, but get 2 compilation errors. How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you implement the interface *explicitly*, you need to cast the variable to the interface:

```
((Imy)o).X = 3;
```

`o` is of type `MyImpl` in your code. You need to cast it to `Imy` explicitly to use the interface properties.

---

Alternativly, you could declare `o` as `Imy`:

```
Imy o = new MyImpl();
o.X = 3;
```